# Rails - Render active partial on same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i just attach a screenshot to make it more obvious what im trying to do:

[image]

Is there a way to load a partial dynamically based on which button was pressed?

For example: If Customers is pressed, load the customer partial on the right side. If products, the products partial and so on.

I saw somewhere in some literature some examples where they did that, but can't find it anymore.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in very easier way...
Suppose your button is loaded on index page :-

```
#index.html.erb

.....
  #Your index page code
.....
<%= link_to “customer path”, customer_path, class: "css-class", remote: true %> ## create button with remote true for ajax call
<%= link_to “product path”, product_path, class: "css-class", remote: true %> ## create button with remote true for ajax call

   <div id = "customer-section"> </div> #div to load partials
   <div id = "product-section"> </div> #div to load partials
```

In your controller:

```
#controller.rb

def customer
 #customer code here
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js  {}
 end
end

def product
 #product code here
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js  {}
 end
end
```

Create js file :-

```
# customer.js.erb
$("#customer-section").html("<%=j render "customer")%>");

# product.js.erb
$("#product-section").html("<%=j render "product")%>");
```

Create partial html file to render :-

```
# _customer.html.erb
<h1>This is customer partial</h1>


# _product.html.erb
<div>This is product partial</div>
```

This way you can achieve your above requirement. For more you can refer this article https://m.patrikonrails.com/how-to-make-ajax-calls-the-rails-way-20174715d176

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: For some reason, my comment disappeared! Thank you again for this! This was exactly what i was looking for! I saw this pattern before but totally forgot how to do it properly!